# Protractor wait for async function used in expect check

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, protractor

Hei,

I'm using protractor to run e2e tests, and would like to have something of the sort:

```
expect(element(by.model('someModel')).getText()).toContain(asyncMethodResult());
```

I would like to avoid doing:

```
asyncMethodResult().then(function(result){
    expect(element(by.model('someModel').getText()).toContain(result);
});
```

Also possibly run an async request in a beforeEach which also 'blocks' further execution until done

Is that doable? is something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait.for the only way to do so?

[Update] For the sake of answer:

```
it('test spec', function () {
   var expectFn = function (x, t) {
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Timeout complete:', x, t);
        deferred.resolve(x);
      }, t);
      return deferred.promise;
   };
   expect(expectFn(3, 1000)).toEqual(expectFn(4, 2000));
}
```

Passes or fails correctly (depending on x values) if:

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Y); //where Y > promise timeout value
```

In this case protractor waits for 'Y' millis, then compares the values, otherwise compares always passes.

If the implicitWait is less than the timeout, then it always passes immetiatly

Answer (score 3):

Your first case (`expect(...).toContain(asyncMethodResult())` should already work. See an example test [here](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/blob/master/spec/adapterSpec.js#L120).

It is also possible to run an async request in a `beforeEach` block. Here's an example:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    doSyncStuff();
    doAsyncStuff.then(done);
});
```

Comment: I was testing that with 'testFn(returnVal, timeout)' (which just calls setTimeout and resolves the promise with returnVal). After your answer I removed the browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000) value we had, and the test always passes:

Comment: I also tried using:  var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
        flow.execute(function () {///ASYNC operations}.then(funciton(){///EXPECTS});  this also timesout/always passes